# Crontab -e doesn't works

Tags: ubuntu, cron

world. I have a Linux-Ubuntu VPS. I want to use crontab, but when I do `crontab -e`I have this:

```
marcobuster@vps:~/$ crontab -e
no crontab for marcobuster - using an empty one
888
#This is a test
0 0 * * * echo TEST
?
test, this is a example
?
^C
?
^Z
[10]+  Stopped                 crontab -e
marcobuster@vps:~/$ crontab -l
no crontab for marcobuster
marcobuster@vps:~/$
```

I can't save. I tried to remove and install cron, change the default editor, with no results.

Comment: Your question looks as if something ate the beginning.

Comment: When you press ^Z the process of editing crontab is paused

Comment: The output you show is because `crontab` is using the `ed` editor, and `ed` doesn't understand the things you are typing. Try using `VISUAL=nano crontab -e` or `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` (replace `nano` with the editort of your choice)

Comment: You're hitting `^Z` which backgrounds the edit process so it's now still in the background having not saved the file. You need to hit `^D` to say you're done. Or set the `EDITOR` environment variable.